# A question on terminology regarding axiomatizations

Tags: model-theory

Suppose you have a first order theory in some fixed language $L$. If the axiomatization only has an AE axiomatization, it would be considered $\Pi_2$ and if it is only EA it would be $\Sigma_2$.

Suppose that you have an axiomatization where some of the sentences are AE  some others are EA. My question is what would you call the axiomatization? It is $\Pi_3$, but is it $\Pi_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not $\Pi_2$. I've seen the notation "$\Pi_2\wedge\Sigma_2$" to describe such theories, although it's potentially ambiguous - it does *not* mean "both $\Pi_2$ and $\Sigma_2$".

Comment: Would $\Delta_2$ work?

Comment: @dav11 No. "$\Delta_2$" means "both $\Pi_2$ and $\Sigma_2$". (That is, every $\Delta_2$ theory is $\Pi_2$ and is $\Sigma_2$, and every $\Pi_2$ theory and every $\Sigma_2$ theory is $\Pi_2\wedge\Sigma_2$, and none of these inclusions reverse.)

Comment: Ah, so $\Delta_3$ should work.....

Comment: @dav11 That would work, but note that $\Delta_3$ is more inclusive than $\Pi_2\wedge\Sigma_2$. Not every $\Delta_3$ theory is $\Pi_2\wedge\Sigma_2$.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for your help!